# Unique device id

Tags: android

Is there any unique id on Android Mobile?? If it is then how many digit it has? 
How can I access that through my program??

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: It is also difficult to understand what's the purpose of the id, what's your use for it. Such information would help in giving you an answer. And..yes, you should go over your questions and mark the correct answers: http://stackoverflow.com/users/406494/deepak

Comment: RYAN : How do I accept an answer?? Please tell me the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems that occur when using IMEI, IMSI... that are described here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

The **recommended approach** is to use:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

```
String unique_id = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Are you sure that IMEI is dependent on SIM Card? Because I think, IMEI is used by the GSM mobile phones. For the CDMA mobile phones this unique id is dependent on the mobile phones. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I was confusing IMEI with IMSI.  IMEI is dependent on the phone itself.  I personally prefer the ANDROID_ID because it is a nice 64-bit hex string.  For security and licensing operations, it is easier to do bit-wise operations on it so that you don't have a plain-text string sitting in your compiled code.

Comment: Aaron: We can make change in ANDROID_ID by making factory reseting. Is there way to handle Factory RESET??

Comment: That is the big downside to using ANDROID_ID.  You could just take the first 15 characters of the IMEI.  On my phone this number was hexadecimal, but you should double check that all phones output in this format before you depend on it.

Answer (score 4):

check IMEI.

http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_getting_the_imsi_-_imei_sim-device_unique_ids-t446.html

Comment: Just a note: I found out that the IMEI/IMSI can contain letters and may be longer than 15... just in case you store it in the database with predefined column length...

It seems that android can be installed on devices which store unique device identifier in a different way/format...

Answer (score 3):

For detailed instructions on how to get a Unique Identifier for each Android device your application is installed from, see this official Android Developers Blog posting:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

It seems the best way is for you to generate one your self upon installation and subsequently read it when the application is re-launched.

I personally find this acceptable but not ideal. No one identifier provided by Android works in all instances as most are dependent on the phone's radio states (wifi on/off, cellular on/off, bluetooth on/off). The others like Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID must be implemented by the manufacturer and are not guaranteed to be unique.

The following is an example of writing data to an INSTALLATION file that would be stored along with any other data the application saves locally.

```
public class Installation {
    private static String sID = null;
    private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

    public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
        if (sID == null) {  
            File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
            try {
                if (!installation.exists())
                    writeInstallationFile(installation);
                sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return sID;
    }

    private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        f.readFully(bytes);
        f.close();
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        out.write(id.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }
}
```